# Multiple (dynamic) EditText and onFocusChange problems

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext

I generate multiple `EditText` in a for-loop and want to update a "score" when focus is lost from one of the `EditText`s. I also wish to check that the input is valid and if not, empty the EditText and set focus back to it.

The following code adds `EditTexts` and a `onFocusChangeListener`.

The problem is that when a score is not valid (`updateScore(id)` returns false), I want to empty the `EditText` and set the focus back to this view.

The problem in my code is that if I enter a value in `EditText` **A** that are not valid, and then click in `EditText` **B**. Both **A** *and* **B** have focus... I only want A to have focus...

How can I set the focus back to the previous EditText and be ready for new inputs to this view?

```
    for (int player = 0; player < numPlayers; player++)
    {
        EditText valueET = new EditText(this);

         valueET.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
         @Override public void onClick(View v) {
               Log.v("Focus", "Lagrer unna den som har blitt klikket, " + String.valueOf(v.getId()));
               etHasFocus = (EditText) v;
           }
         });

        valueET.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          
           public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
           if(!hasFocus)
           {
               if(!updateScore(v.getId()))
               {
                 if (etHasFocus != null && v.getId() != etHasFocus.getId()) 
                     etHasFocus.clearFocus();               

                   v.requestFocus();
             }
           });

         valueET.setId(200+player*100+row);
         valueET.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
         valueET.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
         valueET.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

         tr.addView(valueET);
    }
tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

The code for updateScore(id) is (simplified):

```
boolean updateScore(int id)
{
    EditText t = (EditText) findViewById(id);
    String text = t.getText().toString();
    if( !text.equals(""))
    {
        int score = Integer.parseInt(text);
    }
    if(score != 9)
         return false;

        TextView total = (TextView) findViewById(ID_toal);
        t2.setText(String.valueOf(score));
        return true;
}
```

---

Code is updated, problem now is that onClick never is called... (So etHasFocus = null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try keeping a track of which `EditText` has been clicked. For this, create a EditText variable:

```
EditText etHasFocus;
```

In addition to adding `OnFocusChangeListener`, add an `OnClickListener` as well:

```
valueET.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        etHasFocus = (EditText) v;
    }
});
```

Now, inside your `OnFocusChangeListener`, make the following changes:

```
valueET.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!hasFocus) {

            if(!updateScore(v.getId())) {

                // Clear focus from another EditText
                if (etHasFocus != null && v.getId() != etHasFocus.getId()) {
                    etHasFocus.clearFocus();                       
                }

                v.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Edit:**

You are right. the `onClick(View)` method is called on second click. I can suggest you an alternate approach. I have tried it and its working fine:

Create a EditText variable:

```
EditText etCurrent;
```

Set an `OnTouchlistener` on each EditText:

```
valueET.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            if (etCurrent != null) {
                if (etCurrent.getId() != v.getId()) {

                    if (!check(etCurrent.getId())) {
                        etCurrent.setSelection(0,
                                 etCurrent.getText().toString().length());
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        etCurrent = (EditText) v;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                etCurrent = (EditText) v;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

Remove `OnClickListener`, `onFocusChangeListener` and `etHasFocus`.

You don't need to initialize `etCurrent` as `if (etCurrent != null) { } else { }` takes care of that.

Comment: Is it possible to use OnclickListener with EditText? I have added it, but it is never called...

Comment: It's very much possible: [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)). Can you post the updated code?

Comment: It seems that the (!hasFocus) is called before a new EditText gets focus... It also seems that the new EditText that are click not call onClick before I click the second time...

Comment: @EirikO I have added an edit to my answer. See if it solves your problem.